# Functions on Save, Edit, Delete button

Tags: mysql, database, button, save, sql-delete

Please help me what codes to put on save, edit, delete buttons. I created an employee information management. Also how to integrate this button to my database (mysql). Example when I click save it will automatically save in my database or when I click delete it will also delete the selected data in database.

Answer (score 1):

With your limited description what I can suggest is:

1. create ui and button in what ever language you are using.
2. learn how to fire query in that language. Then use this on click of buttons.
3. for save button fire an insert query. Example: `insert into table values('11','harry');`
4. for delete button fire a delete query for particular record. Example: `delete from table where id=1;`
5. for edit button fire an update query for particular record. Example `update table set name='Joy' where id='22';`

Comment: i am sorry for the limited description.. actually i have created a form in java with these three buttons, now i don't know what codes to put on those three buttons to function accordingly...

Comment: @Alvin: see [this](http://www.beginner-java-tutorial.com/java-addressbook.html) for reference.